# Does JaVers work with GraalVM native images?

Tags: graalvm, javers, graalvm-native-image

[GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) compiles Java programs into native executables. Certain Java features, such as reflection, are [not available or limited](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/Reflection/) there. Since [JaVers uses reflection](https://javers.org/features#json-serialization): Does JaVers fully work in a GraalVM native executable?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tested Javers on GraalVM. If GraalVM does not fully supports the `java.util.reflect` package, which is extensively used by Javers -- well, how Javers are supposed to work?